# How to generate a formula in SMTLIB2 format from z3 solver

Tags: z3

I build the formula in z3 using the java API.
However, I have some formula that are difficult to solve, and I want to investigate why. Therefore, I want to print the formula in SMTLIB2 format.

Is it possible to get that from a `Solver` object. Currently, what I can get is only an array of assertions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [Solver.toString()](http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/classcom_1_1microsoft_1_1z3_1_1_solver.html#ad146fa8579a5f8a876c4688cc5a68520) does that. This should also include the variable/constant declarations if you are using the latest master; I think that part was added after the last release.